# Paypal IPN INVALID message When has special chacracters

Tags: php, paypal, special-characters, paypal-ipn

When I do a payment by credit card on paypal sandbox, I fill some special characters (ex: !@#@%^*&*) on address 1/address 2 text fields.
After payment, I get a IPN message, post back to PP and receive a INVALID message (HTTP error 200).

I set UTF-8 on profile/language on PP. But the problem is still there.

Remark: The payment process works fine if I pays by using PP account (means log in and click payment button).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be careful to send to Paypal the exact data you received in the IPN call, with the notable exception of the `cmd` parameter, which has to be set to `_notify-validate`.

Here is some PHP code that takes the raw POST data, parses it to an array, changes the `cmd` parameter, converts it back to POST data, and sends it to Paypal. Getting the raw POST data allows to bypass PHP's built-in parsing, which may apply messy things such as magic quotes, depending on your configuration.

```
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
parse_str($post, $data);
$data['cmd'] = '_notify-validate';
$post = http_build_query($data);

$ch = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($result == 'VERIFIED') {
    // process the payment
}
```

Comment: Although this question is old it really helped me. It even allowed me to avoid having to deal with character encoding issues! So thanks! :)